# Configuring yaml file

Tags: kubernetes

I'm learning k8s, I found an example in the MS docs. The problem I'm having is that I want to switch what GITHUB repo thats being used. I havent been able to figure out the path within this yaml example

```
 apiVersion: apps/v1
 kind: Deployment
 metadata:
   name: azure-vote-back
 spec:
    replicas: 1
    selector:
      matchLabels:
  app: azure-vote-back
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
      app: azure-vote-back
  spec:
    nodeSelector:
    "kubernetes.io/os": linux
  containers:
  - name: azure-vote-back
    image: mcr.microsoft.com/oss/bitnami/redis:6.0.8
    env:
    - name: ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD
      value: "yes"
    resources:
      requests:
        cpu: 100m
        memory: 128Mi
      limits:
        cpu: 250m
        memory: 256Mi
    ports:
    - containerPort: 6379
      name: redis
    ---
    apiVersion: v1
    kind: Service
    metadata:
     name: azure-vote-back
    spec:
      ports:
      - port: 6379
    selector:
    app: azure-vote-back
    ---
    apiVersion: apps/v1
    kind: Deployment
    metadata:
       name: azure-vote-front
         spec:
    replicas: 1
      selector:
       matchLabels:
     app: azure-vote-front
    template:
  metadata:
    labels:
      app: azure-vote-front
  spec:
     nodeSelector:
        "kubernetes.io/os": linux
  containers:
  - name: azure-vote-front
    image: mcr.microsoft.com/azuredocs/azure-vote-front:v1
    resources:
      requests:
        cpu: 100m
        memory: 128Mi
      limits:
        cpu: 250m
        memory: 256Mi
    ports:
    - containerPort: 80
    env:
    - name: REDIS
      value: "azure-vote-back"
    ---
    apiVersion: v1
    kind: Service
    metadata:
    name: azure-vote-front
 spec:
   type: LoadBalancer
   ports:
   - port: 80
   selector:
app: azure-vote-front
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This YAML example doesn't have a Github Repo field at all. That's why you can't find a path.

If you're trying to change the container image source, it has to be from a container registry (or your own filesystem), which is located at

```
containers: image: mcr.microsoft.com/azuredocs/azure-vote-front:v1
```

where mcr.microsoft.com is the container registry.

You won't be able to connect this directly to a Github Repository, but any container registry will work, and I believe Github has one at https://ghcr.io (that link itself will direct you back to Github)